# ASP.NET, C#, RavenDB: error when running a web service located on another computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, ravendb

[image: Error]

Hello everyone. 
I have implemented an ASP.NET web service that performs a query on a RavenDB database. I have then called this service by clicking on a button of a web page that is part of my web site and it is working just fine. I have generated a package from this web site. I have imported this package on IIS 8 located in another machine of the network I am connected to. On this other machine, when I launch the web site, is it working, but when I try to access the service by clicking on a button of a web page, I get the error displayed in the enclosed file. Is this error due to the fact that the web site is unable to locate the web service? If so, how can I fix it? If not, where does this error comes from?
Thanks in advance.